# Query using a SQL reference table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a standard sql database which contains ID, title and description columns but also contains location, category division etc.. that are int values.
I have a second **reference** sql database which contains an ID column, a reference column and a description column. The ID column has a 2char reference value which reflects what type of data it is holding (CA for category, DI for division etc..)

I would like to display these results in a table, but am unable to write the proper Query.

For example: the title **ABC** with the description **letters** has a location of **1** a category of **2** and a division of **3** needs compare the location, category and division with the same reference table and return the appropriate description text.

```
Data database
ID | Title | Description | location | category | division |
------------------------------------------------------------
1111 | ABC | letters     |    1     |    2      |    3   |
1112 | ASD | asdasd      |    3     |    2      |    3   |

Reference Database
ID | Reference | Description |
------------------------------
LO | 1        | The location |
DI | 3        | division words | 
CA | 2        | category words |
DI | 1        | ALL |
```

I want to have a table that returns

```
ID | Title | Description | location |    category    | division |
------------------------------------------------------------------
1111 | ABC | letters | The location | category words | division words |
```

So far, I have

```
select  ID
    ,title
    ,description
    ,location
    ,category
    ,division
    ,reference.description as CAname
from data
left join reference on data.category = reference.reference
where id_type = 'CA'
```

I hope this is clear,

Comment: Show what you've done so far...

Comment: I am not following how the two tables are related. It looks like you have a bad schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a starting point.

```
SELECT dt.ID,dt.Title,dt.description,
       L1.Description as LocationDescription,
       L2.Description as CategoryDescription  ...

FROM data dt
JOIN Reference L1 on dt.location=L1.Reference and L1.ID=='LO'
JOIN Reference L2 on dt.category=L2.Reference and L2.ID=='CA'
```

I agree with Mike's comment though, this is a bad schema design

Comment: I don't quite understand what the l1 and l2 are doing/ what their purpose is.

Comment: You will have to join to the table once for each field you need to match to data in the referce table. If you have 4 fields that is 4 joins (one of the reasons someone said this was a poor design). Each of those tables must have a unique alias, hence L1, L2.

Comment: This gives me the error:
    Msg 107, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
    The column prefix 'l1' does not match with a table name or alias     name used in the query.

Comment: MySQL might be case-sensitive on queries, try making sure your L1 and L2 cases match exactly.   I don't work with MySQL so I am not sure though